# Proper way to include builds from react apps into Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, reactjs, flask

I have a site developed entirely using flask. It uses a Blueprint called `dashboards`, which hosts some views to access different visualizations, i.e   `dashboards/<string: dashboard_name>`

I store my dashboards with an `id`, a `name` and the `group` it belongs to, so users can only access the visualizations from the group they also belong to.

(This is my unexperienced approach to solve this problem, so I'm also open to suggestions of a better design pattern to achieve this.)

My project kinda looks like this

```
app
├── dashboards
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── views.py
├── __init__.py
├── models
│   ├── dashboard.py
│   └── __init__.p
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── styles.css
│   └── js
│       └── scripts.js
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    └── dashboards
        ├── cat.html
        ├── clock.html
        ├── index.html
        ├── private.html
        └── public.html
```

my views for the Dashboard blueprint

```
# app/dashboards/views.py

from ..models.dashboard import Dashboard

@dashboards.route('/<string:name>')
def view_dashboard(name):
    # a dictionary with dashboards available to current_user
    dashboards = get_dashboards() 

    for dashboard in dashboards.values():
        for d in dashboard:
            if name == d.name:
                route = 'dashboards/{dashboard}.html'.format(dashboard = d.name)
                return render_template(route, dashboard=d)
    else:
        return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

and for the Dashboard blueprint

```
# app/dashboards/__init__.py

from flask import Blueprint

dashboards = Blueprint('dashboards', __name__)

from . import views
```

finally, I use the create_app pattern

```
# app/__init__.py

# some imports happening here

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    from .dashboards import dashboards as dashboards_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(dashboards_blueprint, url_prefix='/dashboards')

    return app
```

One level above the `app`, there is a `manage.py` that calls the `create_app` method, passing some configuration attributes. I believe this is a common pattern in Flask. I also believe this is not relevant to my question.

Particularly, if one deploys a react app using the create-react-app package, i.e.  using `npm run build`, the output is a folder `/build` that contains the static files necessary to run the app. This folder has, for instance the following structure

```
├── build
│   ├── asset-manifest.json
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── manifest.json
│   ├── service-worker.js
│   └── static
│       ├── css
│       │   ├── main.<some-hash-1>.css
│       │   └── main.<some-hash-1>.css.map
│       └── js
│           ├── main.<some-hash-2>.js
│           └── main.<some-hash-2>.js.map
other files here
```

Now if want to plug this react-app using Flask, what I do now is to move the files in `/css` and `/js` of `/build` to the `/static` folder inside `/app`, and rename `index.html` from `/build` into let's say 'react-dashboard.html' and move it to `templates/dashboards`.

This is a very dumb approach to make basic apps working, but I don't know where to place the other files from `/build`, and lest about a better design pattern.

From this [README](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/#static-files) I get that I can tweak the blueprint definition and move my template and static folder inside `app/dashboards`, but I still don't know where other files as `service-worker.js`, and manifests and so on.

What is the proper  way to "mount" my deployed react app on my Flask application? I understand that reorganizing files from `/build` is something not desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it tweaking the blueprint

```
bp = Blueprint(name='myblueprint', 
                    import_name=__name__,
                    static_folder='static/myblueprint',
                    template_folder='templates',
                    static_url_path='/static', # this is what myblueprint.static will point to
                    url_prefix='/myblueprint', 
                    subdomain=None,
                    url_defaults=None, 
                    root_path=None)
```

With this, my static paths inside the blueprint will point to `/myblueprint/static`, and I will need to modify my `create-react-app` build folder.

- replace calls to `static` in every *.css, *.js and .html in `/build` to `/myblueprint/static`
- rearrange folders inside `/build` to match my blueprint `static` folder.

  - Move `/build/static` to `/blueprint/static`
  - Set my own jinja template in `/blueprint/templates/index.html` that calls these files. Make sure this file points to the static assets in `/myblueprint/static` and not to `/build/static`.

I've created a `gulpfile` that will automate this process,

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

// script to deploy react build into flask blueprint directory
// it replaces values and folder names

// README
// how to use this:
// in the react app, run npm run build
// copy the resulting /build folder in /myblueprint
// create a template of a template in /templates/base as index.default.html

// install gulp, gulp-replace, gulp-rename
// run gulp from /myblueprint


// replace routes inside css files

gulp.task('othertemplates', function(){
  gulp.src(['./build/static/css/main.*.css'])
    .pipe(replace('url(/static/media/', 'url(/myblueprint/static/media/'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('static/myblueprint/css/'));
});

// replace routes inside js files

gulp.task('jsthingtemplates', function(){
  gulp.src(['./build/static/js/main.*.js'])
    .pipe(replace('static/media/', 'myblueprint/static/media/'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('static/myblueprint/js/'));
});

// move other files

gulp.task('mediastuff', function(){
  gulp.src(['./build/static/media/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('static/myblueprint/media/'));

  gulp.src(['./build/asset-manifest.json'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('static/myblueprint/'));
});

// replace hashes in assets in the jinja template

gulp.task('jinjareplace', function(){

  var fs = require('fs');
  var assets = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./build/asset-manifest.json'));

  // extract hashes

  let jsHashNew = assets['main.js'].match('[a-z0-9]{8}')
  let cssHashNew = assets['main.css'].match('[a-z0-9]{8}')

  gulp.src(['./templates/myblueprint/base/index.default.html'])
    .pipe(replace('css/main.cssHash.css', `css/main.${cssHashNew}.css`))
    .pipe(replace('js/main.jsHash.js', `js/main.${jsHashNew}.js`))
    .pipe(rename('index.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('templates/myblueprint/'));
});


gulp.task('default', ['othertemplates', 'jsthingtemplates', 'mediastuff', 'jinjareplace'])
```

with this, you can run `gulp` from the same path as `gulpfile.js` and should have everything covered.